# What does navbar-collapse bootstrap class do?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably a noob question.

The thing is, I see this `navbar-collapse` class popping out a lot in bootstrap examples, along with `navbar-responsive-collapse`, but I can't find a proper description of them in the official documentation, nor, and that's the weirdest thing to me, the class is to be found in bootstrap CSS/JS.

Can someone explain this to me? Why aren't the classes in the CSS? What am I using them for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navbar-collapse refers to the menu that is in the mobile view with the navbar (contains links, and toggle-friendly content). They are in the bootstrap CSS (see [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L50)).

See [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) for a full rundown of how the navbar and collapse work together.

Comment: You are absolutely right, they are in the CSS. They just weren't in the CSS I downloaded from a screencasts website. Weird. I apologize.